# Accessing dynamically allocated structure received through socket

Tags: c, sockets, struct

I am transferring dynamically allocated structure from server to client.The entire structure is received in client side, but I get segmentation fault when accessing the structure element in client side.

server code:

```
struct structure *struct1 = malloc(sizeof(struct structure)*count);

bytes = send(sockfd, (void*)&struct1, sizeof(struct structure));
```

client code:

```
struct structure *struct1 = malloc(sizeof(struct structure)*count);

bytes = recv(sockfd, (void*)&struct1, sizeof(struct structure));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`send()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/send) function prototype is

```
ssize_t send(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags);
```

The second argument should be of type `const void *`.

The problem in your code is that you're not passing a *pointer to the buffer*, you're passing a *pointer to the pointer* to the buffer. Also, the typecasting is wrong.

change

```
(void)&struct1
```

to

```
(const void *)struct1
```

Note: IMO, this will work [*maybe better*] without the cast. Give it a try.

Comment: I would suggest without (explicit) cast. C allows automatic casting to `void *` and casting type `T` to `const T` is also implicit.

Comment: @Gyapti Right you are. I left the code _with_ the cast to show the error in that part.

Answer (score 2):

You are typecasting the address of pointer to the void pointer. Make that

```
(void*)struct1.
```

Remove the ampersand(&).

Answer (score 2):

In [c](/questions/tagged/c) You don't need to **explicitly** cast the address to `void *`. Better offload this to compiler if proper headers are included.

Rewrite your calls to send and recv as

```
send(sockfd,struct1, sizeof(struct structure));
recv(sockfd, struct1, sizeof(struct structure));
```

Also as a side note, you should check the whether call to `malloc` was successful or not by writing something like:

```
if(NULL == struct1) {
  /* Error: malloc failed */
}
```